# Why can I not echo the value of this multimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

This is so incredibly basic that I am totally baffled as to why it doesn't work. I have an array called `$elements`, and I want to just echo out one of the values.

I use NetBeans as an IDE, and if I use that to examine the contents of the multidimensional array in question, it looks like this:

[image: view of array in Netbeans]

So far as I can tell, everything looks normal. It is a multidimensional array, where the first level is numbered "0", and the second level has four named entries.

I just want to echo the value of "parameters", which is a string.

However, this code outputs nothing:

```
echo "This is the value of 'parameters': " .  $elements[0]['parameters'];
```

Have I got this most basic code wrong in some way?

---

This is what I get if I do `var_dump($elements)`:

> array(1) { [0]=> object(Element)#3 (4) { ["type":"Element":private]=>
>   string(4) "Text" ["resource":"Element":private]=> string(1) "0"
>   ["parameters":"Element":private]=> string(209) "IP1 111.111.111.111
>   IP2 222.222.222.222 IP3 333.333.333.333 IP4 444.444.444.444 IP5
>   555.555.555.555 IP6 666.666.666.666 IP7 777.777.777.777 IP8 888.888.888.888 IP9 999.999.999.999 IP10 111.111.111.112" ["parent":"Element":private]=> NULL } }

... and this is the output from `print_r($elements)`:

```
Array ( [0] => Element Object ( [type:Element:private] => Text [resource:Element:private] => 0 [parameters:Element:private] => IP1 111.111.111.111 IP2 222.222.222.222 IP3 333.333.333.333 IP4 444.444.444.444 IP5 555.555.555.555 IP6 666.666.666.666 IP7 777.777.777.777 IP8 888.888.888.888 IP9 999.999.999.999 IP10 111.111.111.112 [parent:Element:private] => ) )
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I've added the var_dump output to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your var dump is saying that element 0 is an object, so you will need to access it like so:

```
echo $elements[0]->parameters;
```

The problem is that from your dump, the `parameters` element is marked as private, so you will not be able to access it.

Solutions are:

- Change `parameters` to public
- Write a getter (`getParameters()`) and use that method to get your parameters.

Comment: I was vaguely aware that this was an object, but for some reason I thought objects and arrays could be treated more or less the same. Now I know better. Thanks for clearing it up for me!

Answer (score 1):

Entry 0 at `$elements` is not just an array of attributes it's a class `Element` instance so in order to access its properties do something like:

```
echo( $elements[ 0 ]->parameters );
```

Although the `parameters` field seems private so you'd better add an accessor method to the object like `getParameters()` which would be public and return the value of parameters.

Comment: Thank you for answering - the only reason I gave the check to the other answer was because it was answered slightly earlier, and I only went by that because I needed at least something to differentiate. Hope that's understandable.